# How can I call a function with a variable and pass it as a parameter? Jquery

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is this:

I want to simply call a function as an argument. How can I achieve this? What I"m doing right now is not working.

```
function foo() {
    msg = 'hi';
    myFunc = greetings();
    heyuser(msg, myFunc);
}

function heyuser(msg, myFunc) {
    alert(msg);
    myFunc();
}

function greetings() {
    alert ('greetings');
}
```

Comment: You want to reference function: `myFunc = greetings;`. Using `myFunc = greetings();`, `myFunc` would be the returned value of `greetings` method, which here is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed pass a function as a parameter. The only mistake you've made is *calling* the function when you intend to just get the reference at this line:

```
     myFunc = greetings();
```

Instead simply do remove the brackets and you will instead assign the variable myFunc to be equal to the function reference:

```
     myFunc = greetings;
```